# git show remote branches, and filter out HEAD and any other symbolic references

Tags: git

I am writing a script that takes a git repo, and it runs a test for each remote branch. I use the following to get the names of the remote branches:

```
$ git branch -l -r
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/br1
```

however, I also get symbolic references, such as HEAD. How to I filter out HEAD and any other symbolic reference?

Comment: `git branch -l -r|grep -v -- '->'` ?

Comment: sure, but this hack is very unreliable. how to know all "exceptions"...

Comment: Just an idea: did you check the .git folder?  Maybe you can find useful files with information about references. Chapter 10 could be useful: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: i wouldn't like to play with the internals ;) finally i've used a java git implementation: https://gist.github.com/dportabella/3dbd22333012682210b6d6ee2e50118d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you want to operate on a set of references, the correct plumbing (script-able) command is likely to be `git for-each-ref`.

In this case, for instance:

```
$ git for-each-ref --format '%(refname)' refs/remotes |
> while read ref; do
>     if git symbolic-ref -q $ref > /dev/null; then
>         echo sym $ref
>     else
>        echo reg $ref
>    fi
> done
sym refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
reg refs/remotes/origin/maint
reg refs/remotes/origin/master
reg refs/remotes/origin/next
reg refs/remotes/origin/pu
reg refs/remotes/origin/todo
```

To skip the symbolic references entirely, you can change the if/then clause to `if ! git symbolic-ref -q $ref > /dev/null; then` (and drop the `else` entirely).  To do something interesting with the symbolic references and their targets, save the output from `git symbolic-ref` in a variable, instead of redirecting it to `/dev/null` (but retain the `-q` to prevent it from complaining to stderr for all non-symbolic refs).

The `for-each-ref` command lets you operate on any sensible subset of references, including specific remotes, or all local branches (`refs/heads`).